# NullPointerException with HashMap<Integer,Double> when input is double

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

**Introduction** 
I am having some difficulties with figuring out what's causing me to get a NullPointerException in a HashMap that should be fairly simple. To understand why I am using a HashMap I think the best way to describe it is to say that I have a Multithreaded program which has some results I would like to store. In that context I have created a class called `SaveMethod` which will be used to store values from the process. Since one never knows which thread that will finish first I use a `HashMap` to store thread `i`'s value in this hashmap as follows:

**Code:** 
First the definition of the HashMap:

```
// The first Integer element is the thread index, the second is the Double value
private static HashMap<Integer,Double> AUC = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();
```

Then I call this method ones a thread terminates for storage:

```
public static void setAUC(double AUC,int i){        
    Double AUCtemp = AUC;
    SaveMethod.AUC.put(i,AUCtemp);
}
```

**Some more description:** 
Now, I have previously had success implementing above functionality by the usage of:

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Double[]> AUC = new HashMap<Integer,Double[]>();
```

That is, compared to the previous example, `Double[]` instead of `Double`. And that has worked pretty well.

**Question** 
My question is twofold: 1)
Why am I getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to call this code:

```
    public static Double getAUC(int i){
        double AUC = SaveMethod.AUC.get(i);
        return AUC;
    }
```

2) is this saving option thread safe?

**Some additional reasoning why I need this:**

let me try and justify why I need this storage option. I have a set of calculations that need to be performed, lets say 100. Each calculation takes approximately 10 seconds. Now, to reduce computational time I have implemented Multithread so that these calculations can be done simultanously. But these calculations does not depend on each other in any way. However, I need to store each result from each thread (which is a lot of different values/matrixes etc.) for each computation, so that the results can be reached globally from other methods/classes for plotting purpose. What do you recon is the way to store the results from the calculation AND maintain a thread-safe enviroment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Why am I getting Exception in thread "main"

Because there's presumably no value for the given integer, so the `get` call returns `null`. You're then unboxing that, which throws an exception. Your code is effectively:

```
public static Double getAUC(int i){
    Double temp = SaveMethod.AUC.get(i); // This can return null
    double AUC = temp.doubleValue(); // This was auto-unboxing

    Double boxed = Double.valueOf(AUC); // This was boxing
    return boxed;
}
```

If you want to just return `null` instead if the key is missing, just avoid ever converting to `Double`. Your method can be as simple as:

```
public static Double getAUC(int i) {
    return SaveMethod.AUC.get(i);
}
```

It's not clear whether you *want* to just return `null` though, or throw some other kind of exception.

> 2) is this saving option thread safe?

Well `HashMap` isn't thread-safe to start with, so no... consider using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead.

Comment: What would you do if you where to build a class which had to purpose to store a lot of calculations AND it should be thread safe?

Comment: @SteewDK: Well I'd consider using `ConcurrentHashMap` to start with. But it would really depend on the exact behaviour you want - how would you want different threads to interact with each other, if they were performing calculations on the same data?

Comment: So let me try and explain why I need this. 
I have a set of calculations that need to be performed, lets say 100.
Each calculation takes approximately 10 seconds. I have implemented Multithread so that these calculations can be done simultanously (they do not depend on each other) but I need to store each result (a lot of different values) for each computation, so that the results can be reached globally from other methods/classes for plotting. What do you recon is the best to do so?

Comment: @SteewDK: If each calculation has a key that will be distinct from all the others, just using `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably okay. I'm always nervous of global variables, mind you, but that sounds like it's a decision which has already been taken...

Comment: Well, the variables are not global. That is why I created the class SaveMethod. Then every time a computation is done it will be stored in a field HashMap inside the class SaveMethod. 
And yes, each calculation has a distinction from the others, namely the int i (as shown in my example).

Comment: @SteewDK: You've got a static variable which is a map - that's a global variable. It may not be public, but it's still a global variable, with the normal issues around testability etc.

Comment: You are correct, my apologizes. 
What options would you consider instead?

Comment: @SteewDK: That's impossible to say without more information, and is a *long* way from the topic of the question.

Answer (score 3):

1. My guess would be that the value retrieved from the `HashMap` for key `i` is `null`. Java then tries to unbox it from `Double` into a primitive `double` which results in a `NullPointerException`.
2. No, `HashMap` is not thread-safe. But as a starting point you can make `HashMap` thread safe by wrapping it with `Collections.synchronizedMap()`

Comment: What would you do if you where to build a class which had to purpose to store a lot of calculations AND it should be thread safe?

Comment: It depends. Are you trying to load balance work across multiple threads? Is there shared mutable state involved?

Comment: The calculations does not depend on each other.

Comment: The synchronized `HashMap` is a good starting point. Make sure to get familiar with concurrency synchronization basics (google is your friend). But as Jon said, this is a rather large topic and out of scope regarding the original question. Good luck.